# как с помощью нажатия кнопки добавлять view элементы?

Tags: android, view

Всем привет. Как добавляются view элементы из кода при нажатии на кнопу? Есть список карточек который реализован с помощью RecyclerView и нужно сделать так чтоб при нажатии на слово "edit" всплывали напротив каждой карточки Checkbox, но нужно сделать это так чтоб при появлении чек боксов карточки сдвигались в сторону, точно так как показано на гифке. С помощью setVisibility() реализовать это не получается, так как при исчезновении чек боксов карточки не сдвигаются обратно а на месте чек боксов остается пустое пространство. Можно спрятать чек боксы с помощью setVisibility(View.GONE), но я не знаю как потом обратно вызывать чек боксы. Нужно сделать точно так как показано на гифке. Заранее благодарю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо `INVISIBLE` используйте `GONE` и должно получиться

Comment: @woesss только что исправил текст а потом увидел ваш коментарий. Я с помощью GONE убираю чек боксы, работает как мне и нужно, но только я не знаю как обратно их востанавливать. То есть в INVISIBLE есть противоположный метод VISIBLE а какой противоположный метод у GONE?

Comment: Так же как и скрываете, только теперь `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` - он же "противоположный" и для `GONE`, вернее все три взаимоисключающие.

Comment: @woesss только что попробовал скрыть с помощью GONE а потом вывести на экран обратно с помощью setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). При вызове метода setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) выдало исключение NullPointerException

Comment: Покажите код раз выдало исключение , знеачит делаете что то не так

Comment: @Романыч вот скрин кода где я пытаюсь при нажатии на кнопку вызвать setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). http://prntscr.com/rwj8q2

Comment: Стоп стапэ я тут щас подумал у вас же RecyclerView? Значит вам нужно отрабатывать прятать айтем Recyclera как бы. И тут сразу реализация становиться по идее немного другого плана

Comment: @Романыч так я в RecyclerView и прячу а точнее во ViewHolder. а вывожу на экран уже во фрагменте при нажатии кнопки. вот код где я прячу во ViewHolder  http://prntscr.com/rwjayh

Comment: Дмаю так это работать точно не будет. Тут преположу что нужен интерфейс на который будет подписан адаптер или вроде того. И при клике адаптер будет бачить изменения и прятать свои чекбоксы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106542/discussion-between--and-artem).